# How can i get data from another collection field by the id

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

So here is the case. I have two model/schema. and I want to get the `bid` field in my job model from bid model

Here is the example when I "POST" the bid model using postman:

```
{
  "price": "8.770.000",
  "negotiation": "this is just example",
  "job" :"5c4192f5da1c3619f4089f5e" //this is job_id
}
```

and when I try to "GET" job model, here is the result:

```
{
  "id": "5c4192f5da1c3619f4089f5e",
  "owner": {
    "id": "5be541622a228a231c6769c2",
    "username": "ceka",
    "rating": 0,
  },
  "title": "create website",
  "description": "this is just description",
  "category": "programming",
  "budget": "2.000.000",
  "remote": true,
  "bid": []
}
```

> the bid is empty

bid model:

```
const bidderSchema = new Schema({
  user: {
   type: Schema.ObjectId,
   ref: 'User',
   required: true
  },
  job: {
   type: Schema.ObjectId,
   ref: "Job",
   required: true
  },
  price: {
   type: String
  },
  negotiation: {
   type: String
  }
}
```

and job model:

```
const jobSchema = new Schema({
 owner: {
  type: Schema.ObjectId,
  ref: 'User',
  required: true
 },
 title: {
  type: String
 },
 description: {
  type: String
 },
 bid: [
  {
   type: Schema.ObjectId,
   ref: 'Bidder'
  }
 ]
}
```

router:

```
export const index = ({ querymen: { query, select, cursor } }, res, next) =>
Job.find(query, select, cursor)
 .populate('owner')
 .then((jobs) => jobs.map((job) => job.view()))
 .then(success(res))
 .catch(next)
```

So the point is I want to get the bid from bid model into job by 'job_id', how can I do that? Is it possible?

Comment: can you show the query here...

Comment: i'm sorry, query of what?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using mongoose, you should be fine just populating the `bid` row too, like this:

```
export const index = ({ querymen: { query, select, cursor } }, res, next) =>
Job.find(query, select, cursor)
 .populate('owner')
 .populate('bid')
 .then((jobs) => jobs.map((job) => job.view()))
 .then(success(res))
 .catch(next)
```

Comment: the bid is empty, so i can't populate it

Comment: so why don't you query for the `Bidder` model by its `job` and populate the job instead? Like this: `Bidder.find({ job: JOBID }).populate('job')`. You can even deep populate the job owner, like this: `Bidder.find({ job: JOBID }).populate('job').populate('job.owner')` if job's owner is not the same as bid's user.